# query join to return two values even if only one exists by query statement

Tags: mysql, join, exists

I'm querying database and i need it to return all values. I'm joining two tables **storage_path** AND **users** First user exists in first and in the second table by user_id field. Second user doesn't exist in table storage_path but i need that user also returned by query!

How can i accomplish this?

Here is the query just to be more clear...

This query is in while loop switching user_id variable

```
$item_id = $row['user_id']; 

$sql = "SELECT MAX(sf.file_id) as file_id, sf.storage_path as image, u.photo_id 
FROM engine4_users u 
LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files sf
    ON sf.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE sf.type = 'thumb.icon' AND u.user_id = $item_id";
```

Comment: Have a look here http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: can you give sample records?

Comment: instead of `left` join perhaps `full outer`? but then you'd have to move your where clause on to the join or you'll eliminate some of the full outer records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem in the query relates to the fact that you've used a MAX selection field but didn't provide the GROUP BY field.

Try this:

```
$sql = "SELECT MAX(sf.file_id) as file_id, sf.storage_path as image, u.photo_id 
FROM engine4_users u 
LEFT JOIN engine4_storage_files sf
    ON sf.user_id = u.user_id 
WHERE sf.type = 'thumb.icon' AND u.user_id = $item_id
GROUP BY u.user_id";
```